# Unable to start live streaming in agora with vp8 codec

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I want to create a live stream with multiple broadcasters/hosts and publish it to RTMP CDN with agora.

I am using [agora-rtc-sdk-ng](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/AgoraWebSDK-NG) library.

As per [documentation](https://agoraio-community.github.io/AgoraWebSDK-NG/docs/en/cdn_streaming) I have tried to start live streaming but it is giving the below error while calling

```
AgoraRTCClient.startLiveStreaming
```

Error :

```
{
  "name": "AgoraRTCException",
  "code": "LIVE_STREAMING_INVALID_RAW_STREAM",
  "message": "AgoraRTCError LIVE_STREAMING_INVALID_RAW_STREAM: raw streaming is only support h264"
}
```

Can anybody help me how to solve this error?

Comment: As suggested by the error, did you try using h264 instead? or is vp8 a strict requirement?

Answer (score 0):

While calling createClient to create a local client object. Pay attention to the settings of the mode and codec parameters when creating the client: just pass the codec to "h264" here is the sample.

```
rtc.client = AgoraRTC.createClient({ mode: "rtc", codec: "h264" });
```

For detailed explanation please visit the agora documentation link here
https://agoraio-community.github.io/AgoraWebSDK-NG/docs/en/basic_call#2join-a-channel